# How do i correctly close idHTTPServer to avoid memory leaks of request threads?

Tags: delphi, indy

idHTTPServer creates thread for each request. Sometimes, my threads work quite long, so when i close server it leaks with unexpected memory blocks. Sometimes everything work without memory leaks, it depends on the moment of app closing. To avoid this i'm trying to do 2 following steps.
1. Server.Active := false or may be go in offline mode.
2. Terminate all request threads // don't know how to do that ((

Is any way to terminate working threads before i close app ?

I realized such approach to long running threads which are my own class of threads like this

```
procedure TMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Stop();

  with LongTaskThreads.LockList() do
  try
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      TLongTaskThread(Items[i]).FreeOnTerminate := false; // in other case they will be destroyed automatically
      TLongTaskThread(Items[i]).Free();
    end;
  finally
    LongTaskThreads.UnlockList();
  end;
end;
```

Is any similar approach to request threads of idHTTPServer ?

Regards, Stan

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Indy should normally manage those thread and make sure they get cleaned up when they are done. Memory for the process is freed anyway when the process ends. A memory leak is mainly a problem if you don't free resources during the run of a program, so if every thread would remain in memory, at some point you would run out of memory, or out of handles (there are only so many threads you can have at a time).

Comment: "*idHTTPServer creates thread for each request*" - no, it does not create a thread per request.  It creates a thread per client connection, and by default those threads are not pooled, but that can optionally be enabled if desired.  A client can send multiple requests per connection if HTTP keep-alives are used, which is the default behavior for HTTP 1.1.

Comment: "*Is any similar approach to request threads of idHTTPServer ?*" - `TIdHTTPServer` handles that for you when its `Active` property is set to False. You don't need to manage the client threads manually.  However, for your own threads, you should terminate them yourself as needed, explicitly using `TThread.Terminate()` and `TThread.WaitFor()` instead of relying on `TThread.Free()` doing it for you

Comment: hm... if i set keep alive, all requests will work in one thread ?